# Passing two paramaters in arrow function React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an arrow function in my react native application.

I am trying to pass first props to be able to navigate between my screens and at the same time I want also to pass in route because I want to pass data between my screens.

However, with the following code I have, whatever I put as the second parameter, it is always undefined... and the first one will work correctly.

Please let me know what I must do to be able to pass in two parameters:

```
const Home = ({route, props}) => {
  {console.log(route.params.id)}
  {console.log(props)}
}
```

I also tried

```
const Home = ({route}, props) => {
  {console.log(route.params.id)}
  {console.log(props)}
}
```

By the way, I am using the latest version of React Native and React Navigation.   I'm using purely functional component

Comment: The second example is invalid `const Home = ({route}, props})`. You have an extra closing `}`.

Comment: I am sorry it was a typo in my question

Comment: With the new change it still does not work?

Comment: Yes it still does not work

Comment: How are you calling `Home`?

Comment: props.navigation.push("Home", data);  Where data is a json format

Comment: ok, this is react specific then. I have not used this.

Comment: It might be useful to see how Home is called by its parent but I suspect what you want to achieve requires the use of the spread operator: `const Home = ({route, ...props})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, I use to like that

```
const Home = (props) => {
  const {route} = props
  {console.log(route.params.id)}
  {console.log(props)}
}
```

Because in component all params are props and only one param is props in component

Answer (score 1):

this not the right way to pass other props. try this.

```
const Home =({route, ...props}) => {
....
}
```